# What makes hard magnetic materials more appropriate for use in microphones than soft magnetic materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics

I can't find a reason out there. Surely it'd be a soft magnetic material is best? What makes hard magnetic materials more appropriate for use in microphones than soft magnetic materials?

Comment: What type of microphone do you have in mind?

Comment: I mean the most common type of microphone, whatever it is.

Comment: Besides wanting an accurate, linear response?

Comment: The most common type of microphone is the electret microphone. This has no magnetic material whatsoever. Where did you get the idea about hard versus soft magnetic material in microphone?

Answer (score 0):

Hard magnetic materials are difficult to demagnetize. This is a desirable property in both magnetic (i.e., moving-coil or "dynamic") microphones and in loudspeakers, which is why soft iron magnets are not used in either.

By the way, dynamic microphones are still the dominant technology for live stage use with sound-reinforcement systems. For example, the Shure SM-57 and -58 models are moving-coil dynamic mics which contain magnets and have been in continuous production for over 50 years.